# When checked multiple checkboxes form fields should appear accordingly with common fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

When the user checks multiple checkboxes, form fields should appear according to the checkboxes, example: if flight checkbox had full name last name, when user checked both hotel and flight the full name and last name should be there and other fields should be hidden.

I have tried a toggle method which hides when I check, but I can not select multiple fields and get the common fields together and hide others. also my checkboxes should be aligned horizontally. I should css but it's not working

```js
function toggle(object) {
    var input;
    var value = object.getAttribute("value");
  
    switch (value) {
        case "flight":
            input = "input1";
            break;
        case "hotel":
            input = "input2";
            break;
        case "travel":
            input = "input3";
            break;
    }
  
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(input);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].style.display == "block") {
            elements[i].style.display = "none";
        } else {
            elements[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.form-style-1 {
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    border-radius: 18px;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.form-style-1 fieldset {
    border-radius: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    width: 550px;
    margin: auto;
}

.form-style-1 lable {
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.form-control {
    width: 550px;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline;
}

output {
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.btn {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

.form-style-1 input[type="text"],
.form-style-1 input[type="date"],
.form-style-1 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-1 input[type="email"],
.form-style-1 input[type="number"],
.form-style-1 input[type="search"],
.form-style-1 input[type="time"],
.form-style-1 input[type="url"],
.form-style-1 input[type="tel"],
.form-style-1 textarea,
.form-style-1 select {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #e8eeef;
    color: #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-style-1 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type="date"]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type="datetime"]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type="email"]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type="number"]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type="search"]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type="time"]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type="url"]:focus,
.form-style-1 input[type="tel"],
.form-style-1 textarea:focus,
.form-style-1 input {}
}

.form-style-1 select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
    height: 15px;
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0);
    background: #d2d9dd;
}

.form-style-1 number {
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: #000000;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 4px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}

.form-style-1 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-1 input[type="button"] {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 29px 15px 29px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #1abc9c;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 10%;
    font-style: normal;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid #16a085;
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-style-1 input[type="submit"]:hover,
.form-style-1 input[type="button"]:hover {
    background: #109177;
}

#travel-form label,
textarea {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
}

#travel-form input,
select {
    margin-left: 1rem;
}

textarea {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 250%;
    padding-bottom: 0.1rem;
}

.common {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    display: none;
}

button {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="form-style-1">
        <form action="mailto:    ?subject=Travel Pre-approval Form " method="post" enctype="text/plain" id="travel-form" onsubmit="test1()">
            <fieldset>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" id="flight" value="flight"><label for="flight">Flight</label>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" id="hotel" value="hotel"><label for="hotel">Hotel</label>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" id="travel" value="travel"><label for="travel">Travel</label>
                <label>Full Name: <input type="text" class="input1 common " id="name" placeholder="Full Name as per Passport"></label><br>
                <label>Date of travel:&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="date" class="input1 common " name="num1" id="date of travel"></label>
                <label>Date of arrival: <input type="date" class="input1 common" name="num2"></label>
                <label>Origin Location: <select name="opt2" id="cost" onchange="calculateTotal()">
                        <option value="select">select</option>
                        <option value="Dubai, United Arab Emirates (DXB-Dubai Intl.)">Dubai, United Arab Emirates (DXB-Dubai Intl.)</option>
                    </select></label>
                <label>Destination Location: <select name="op1" id="locations" onchange="calculateTotal()">
                        <option value="none">none</option>
                        <option value="Aberdeen, Scotland, UK (ABZ)">Aberdeen, Scotland, UK (ABZ)</option>
                    </select></label>
                <label>Mobile Number(Roaming) <input type="tel" id="phone"></label><br>
                <br>
                <label>Company Email Address <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="email address"></label><br>
                <br>
                <label>Passport Number <input type="text" id="passnum" size="5" name="passportnumber"></label>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label>Passport Expiry Date <input type="date" id="passexdate" size="4" name="passportexdate"></label> <br>
                <br>
                <label>Visa Required <select type="checkbox" name="visarequired">
                        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                        <option value="Don't Know">Don't Know</option>
                    </select></label>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label>Visa Expiry Date <input type="date" id="visaexdate" name="visa"> </label>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label>Purpose of Travel <input type="text" rows="6" cols="50" name="purpose Of Travel" form="usrform" placeholder="Purpose Of Travel">
                </label> <br>
                <label>Address Of Place Of Visitrows <input type="text" rows="6" cols="50" name="address" form="usrform" placeholder="Address of the place of Vist">
                </label> <br>
                <br>
                <label>Billable Cost Centre <input type="text" id="billablecostcentre"></label>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label>Billable project code <br> (Select "N/A" otherwise) <input type="text"></label>
                <br>
                <br>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="150" name="comment" form="usrform" placeholder="Comments">

    </textarea>
                <label>Do you need Ground Transfer <select type="checkbox" namegroundtransfer>
                        <option>Yes</option>
                        <option>No</option>
                    </select></label>
                <br>
                <div id="totalCost">Total Cost </div><br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Example: user checked flight and hotel both common fields should appear and other fields should be hidden. also if i can get better css will be nice with checkboxes aligned horizontally

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The code should a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @tuneer thanks for the advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following code, it's a bit shortened and generalized **CSS only** approach of your form, that allows you to toggle form fields conditionally with checkboxes:

```css
.form__field {
 display: block;
}
[class*="--checkbox"] {
 display: inline-block;
}
[data-conditional] {
 display: none;
}
#flight:checked ~ [data-conditional*="flight"] {
 display: block;
}
#hotel:checked ~ [data-conditional*="hotel"] {
 display: block;
}
#travel:checked ~ [data-conditional*="travel"] {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="mailto:?subject=Travel Pre-approval Form " method="POST" enctype="text/plain" id="travel-form" onsubmit="test1()">

 <input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="flight" />
 <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="flight">
  <span class="form__label">Flight</span>
 </label>

 <input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="hotel" />
 <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="hotel">
  <span class="form__label">Hotel</span>
 </label>

 <input class="form__input form__input--checkbox" type="checkbox" id="travel" />
 <label class="form__field form__field--checkbox" for="travel">
  <span class="form__label">Travel</span>
 </label>

 <label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight hotel">
  <span class="form__label">Full Name:</span>
  <input class="form__input" type="text"  placeholder="Full Name as per Passport" />
 </label>

 <label class="form__field form__field--date" data-conditional="flight hotel">
  <span class="form__label">Date of travel:</span>
  <input class="form__input" type="date" />
 </label>

 <label class="form__field form__field--date" data-conditional="flight hotel">
  <span class="form__label">Date of arrival:</span>
  <input class="form__input" type="date" />
 </label>

 <label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="flight">
  <span class="form__label">For Flight only:</span>
  <input class="form__input form__input--text" type="text" />
 </label>

 <label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="hotel">
  <span class="form__label">For Hotel only:</span>
  <input class="form__input form__input--text" type="text" />
 </label>

 <label class="form__field form__field--text" data-conditional="travel">
  <span class="form__label">For Travel only:</span>
  <input class="form__input form__input--text" type="text" />
 </label>

 <div class="form__field form__field--submit">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

> also my checkboxes should be aligned horizontally

this should be satisfied as well by the above snippet

We basically use checkboxes to toggle form fields based on the `data-conditional` attribute (you can call it whatever you like) that contains some value(s) we control to show/hide the form fields. The relatively simple secret-sauce part here is the [general next sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) combined with HTML markup that allows us to use it properly.

I added some more fields that only show up for a single checkbox at the end of the form, to illustrate how the conditional filter works.